# PIC assembly: express integer constant as string at build time

Tags: pic, assembler, ascii, integer

One of my engineers came to me with a question that I can't answer. This is for a project using a PIC16F controller, all written in assembler.

He is defining a constant that he wants his program to use in two different ways: as an integer for use within the program **and** the same integer expressed as an ASCII string for use within his serial communication routines.

The standard way that I have done this in the past is to simply have the PIC convert that constant to an ASCII string at run time.  However, since it is a constant, it should be possible to have the compiler do the conversion.

I've thought about it and the answer doesn't immediately come to mind.

He is defining the constant as follows:

```
  #DEFINE gFORCE_MIN 250
```

He is defining the ASCII equivalent as follows:

```
  #DEFINE gFORCE_MIN_STR "250"
```

The idea is that he modifies only one constant and the assembler automatically converts that constant into the double-quotes delimited ASCII value.

His last attempt returns the following after assembly:

```
  DT "gFORCE value ","gFORCE_MIN"  returns:  gFORCE value gFORCE_MIN
```

He is currently using MPLAB 8.92.

Comment: The search terms you're looking for are "stringify" and "token pasting". See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240353/convert-a-preprocessor-token-to-a-string) over at Stack Overflow.

Comment: If you do a lot of this it might help to install the basic UTF-8 chart which includes char numbers 1 - 255. Those over 127 are considered 8 bit Unicode. The char 250 is ú.

Comment: @brhans Different language.

Comment: @Sparky256 - it's not a character code, it's a number that needs to be represented as a string.